# Gulp reload doesn't work

Tags: gulp, gulp-livereload, gulp-connect

I want use gulp reload on my workflow, but I have trouble with it. When I started via "gulp" command in command line I have server connection, but when I go to my browser there is the massege "Cannot GET /" 
What is it, and how can I solve this problem? Help please.

I have next gulpfile.js:

```
  /**
 * Created by adm on 4/24/2016.
 */
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    notify = require("gulp-notify"),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect');

/*----------Local Server connect----------*/
gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: 'traning_js_skils',
        livereload: true
    });
});

/*----------HTML----------*/
gulp.task('html', function () {
    gulp.src('./src/index.html')
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

/*----------CSS----------*/
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('css/*.css')
        .pipe(minifyCSS({keepBreaks:true}))
        .pipe(rename('common.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('testfiles/'))
        .pipe(livereload());
        /*.pipe(connect.reload());*/
        /*.pipe(notify('Done!'))*/
});

/*----------Watch----------*/
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    livereload();
    gulp.watch('css/*.css', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('index.html', ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'watch', 'connect']);
```

Here is my structure of project:
[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your project directory structure please?

Comment: Of course I can. Look above, I have added structure of my product. If it is important my project worked on angularjs and before I had used node-static server for get json data. Maybe it is some conflict between node-static and gulp connect?

Comment: If the index.html you want to serve is the one in the root the only strage thing I see is the root: 'traning_js_skils' it's possible that livereload is searching the directory traning_js_skils/traning_js_skils? try to put "./" in the root config

Comment: Thank you great! Your tip has changed my situation the error "Cannot GET /" disappeared. I new in using gulp that is why I make such error. 
But my index page still doesn't reload when I change my css file. What the reason can be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put the full answere here:

so for the root.

If your index.html file is the one in the main directory. set the root config to ./

```
connect.server({
        root: './',
        livereload: true
    });
```

For the reloading.

I don't use livereload but in the doc I can see this

```
gulp.task('less', function() {
  gulp.src('less/*.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('less/*.less', ['less']);
});
```

can be that you're missing the .listen()

Comment: Yes, really, it have solved my problem. Thank so much for help, you very help me.